# Is it possible to link a node to itself in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

The specifics of my app requires that a node can be linked to itself. Can it be done in Neo4J? Can a new edge be created between the node and itself using the `CREATE` statement? Will I then be able to obtain it using the `MATCH` query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes, it can be done](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-relationships.html).

Citation from the docs:

> While relationships always have a direction, you can ignore the
>   direction where it is not useful in your application.

```
Note that a node can have relationships to itself as well
```

You can create these relationships just like any others.

```
CREATE (p:Person { name: "Sam" });
MATCH (p:Person { name: "Sam" })
MERGE (p)-[:knows]->(p);
```

Although, for obvious reasons, the directionality of a relationship becomes way less interesting if you're pointing a node to itself because there's no difference between the head and the tail.

Comment: I'd just like to mention here for the completeness' sake that we use neo4j as a rule management engine and sometimes it's useful to explicitly allow or prohibit something from the entity to itself, so this capability isn't completely useless.